# Include GA in a React project

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics, webpack

I followed the documentation and I got to this code to add Google Analytics to my React app:

```
import 'autotrack'

ga('create', 'MY CODE', 'auto');
ga('require', 'urlChangeTracker')
ga('send', 'pageview')
```

But I get the following error:

```
  Line 11:  'ga' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 12:  'ga' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 13:  'ga' is not defined  no-undef
```

How can I solve it? Will I get all the data I currently get with the original GA snippet following this setting and is it worth it to implement code splitting (I'm using Webpack).

Answer (score 10):

You get this error from your ESLint setup because you have used `ga` function without explicitly define it. Since `ga` is a global variable you will be able to remove these error by calling it with global `window` object.

```
window.ga('create', 'MY CODE', 'auto');
```

But I recommend you to look at [react-ga](https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga) library which is a better way to include Google Analytics to react applications.

And I don't see any value of implementing code splitting in this specific case.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't seem to be well integrated with React Router v4.

Comment: @ocram Since React Router v4 has some API changes you have to use a different approach to integrating react-ga with that. This thread will help you to figure out that. https://github.com/react-ga/react-ga/issues/122

Comment: Yeah I read it but it's kind of complex and would add quite some code...